# I used npm install then it gives me an error

Tags: node.js, vue.js

I am using Ubuntu.when I use command npm install then it gives me an error:-
npm ERR! code E401
npm ERR! Unable to authenticate, need: Basic realm="https://npm.fontawesome.com/"
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR! /home/vasu/.npm/_logs/2020-04-11T22_06_49_480Z-debug.log

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jFUX2.png)

Comment: Can you paste what stands in package.json connected with fontawesome?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you tried to install the pro version of fontawesome. If you don't have a subscription for it, then you should run:

`npm install --save @fortawesome/fontawesome-free`

If you have a subscription, follow the steps on this page:

https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/setup/using-package-managers#installing-pro